# Error 400 - redirect_uri_mismatch in Google Console

Tags: amazon-cognito, google-signin, google-developers-console

I'm new to google console and encountering an issue while trying to access my app on Google Console, and the error message I'm encountering is:

**Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch**

I have already added specific URLs to "Authorized JavaScript Origins" and "Authorized Redirect URIs" in line with our AWS Cognito settings for "Allowed Callback URLs" and "Allowed Sign-out URLs."

As app developer, I'm uncertain about the correct URI configuration to resolve this issue. Could anyone provide guidance or point me to resources that can help me to configure the redirect URI correctly?

Your timely assistance is highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Pragyan

Answer (score 0):

In Cognito, Identity Federation flow works like below:

1. Your App redirects to Cognito domain
2. Cognito redirects to OIDC provider *i.e. Google*
3. Google redirects back to Cognito *(as per the callback URL)*
4. Cognito redirects back to your App

So, in the third step, you need supply the right callback URL suggested by Cognito, which is provided below.

```
https://yourDomainPrefix.auth.region.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse
```

This is the URL where Google issues the authorization code that Amazon Cognito exchanges for an OAuth/ID token.

For more details, refer [How do I set up Google as a federated identity provider in an Amazon Cognito user pool?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-google-social-identity-provider)